# How to display all image galleries using ACF and a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type that uses ACF for image galleries. All works as it should on individual custom posts, now I want to display all the image galleries together like one big master image gallery through a loop on a page. It's kind of working - but only one image gallery is being displayed. What can I do to make them all show (currently there are 3 galleries but will grow over time)?

Here is the code that's almost there:

```
 <?php

   $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'galleries', 'nopaging' => true) );
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$images = get_field('image_gallery');
    endwhile;
    
if( $images ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

                     <a href="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>); background-size: cover;"  data-lightbox="gallery"><img class="gallery-image" src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt=""></a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the `while` loop, you only assign the gallery to the `$images` variable, which effectively overwrites that variable with each iteration. So what you get at the end is the gallery for the last post.

In this case, simply include the output in a while loop:

```php
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'galleries', 'nopaging' => true) );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $images = get_field('image_gallery');
    if( $images ) :
        foreach( $images as $image ) :
            ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>); background-size: cover;"  data-lightbox="gallery"><img class="gallery-image" src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt=""></a><?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you sooooo much! That was way simpler than my mind was trying to make it out to be :)